# Python OOP inherited classes

Tags: python, oop

I would like to implement the following structure:

```
class Case(nx.Graph):   
    def __init__(self, case):       
        if case == 1:
            self = Case1()
        if case == 2:
            self = Case2()    

class Case1(Case):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Case1, self).__init__()
        print "Case1"

class Case2(Case):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Case2, self).__init__() 
        print "Case2"
```

For instance, if I create the following object:

```
graph = Case(1)
```

a new Object of the class `Case1` should be created. In the `__init__` of the class `Case1` the `super()` fuction should call the `__init__` function of the `networkx.Graph()`.

If I run that code, the result should be a `networkx.Graph` object called "graph" and it should print `Case1`.

Comment: This pattern is called a class factory, example in PY3: http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Factory.html

Comment: No, you do not want this. Classes shouldn't magically change themselves into other classes, and parent classes shouldn't be aware of their children. If you write `case = Case(x)`, you expect to get an instance of `Case`, not any other class. Have plain `Case1` and `Case2` classes, even if they inherit from a common parent, and leave the decision which class to construct **outside** any of those classes.

Comment: another good link: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2131418

Comment: @deceze It's not entirely frowned upon. Python's class instantiation implicitly supports this, as `Class.__init__` is only called on a new object if `Class.__new__` actually returns an instance of `Class`.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `self = ...`, you are just redefining `self`.  You aren't changing it.  To do what you want, use `__new__` instead:

```
class Case(nx.Graph):
    def __new__(self, case):
        if case == 1:
            return Case1()
        elif case == 2:
            return Case2()
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid argument")
```

You really shouldn't do this, though.  If you want a different instance for a different case, do it when you create the instance, but a class should not depend on its children in order to work.

Comment: and now it's getting buggy because ``Case1`` inherits from ``Case`` and thus also has this ``__new__``-method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What you mean by "do it wehen you create the instance" --> would help me a lot if you could give me an example with that code.

Comment: @lars111: I mean, say `x = Case1()`, not `x = Case(1)`.  It gets buggy when you try to do it this way.  For one thing, since `Case1` and `Case2` inherit from `Case`, you would still need to do `x = Case1(1)` because `__new__` needs that argument.  It just gets really buggy when you make a parent class depend on its children.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is by not invoking `__init__` for the subclasses but putting these in a seperate method, i.e. `setup` and rewriting the `__class__` attribute:

```
class Case(object):   
    def __init__(self, case):
        # Maybe even call the init of the superclass:
        super(Case, self).__init__()
        # Do the setup that is common to all Cases:
        self.setup()
        # Change the class of the instance depending on your case:
        if case == 1:
            self.__class__ = Case1  # No () here!
        elif case == 2:
            self.__class__ = Case2
        else:
            raise ValueError()
        # Call the setup of the subclass
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        print('Setup of Case called.')


class Case1(Case):

    def setup(self):
        print('Setup of Case1 called.')

class Case2(Case):

    def setup(self):
        print('Setup of Case2 called.')
```

when I try to create a `Case1`:

```
a = Case(1)
```

it prints:

```
Setup of Case called.
Setup of Case1 called.
```

But there might even be proper (builtin-modules, packages) recipes for doing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic Factory pattern. I would implement it using a static method as follows:

```
class Case(object):   

    @staticmethod
    def factory(case):
        if case == 1:
            return Case1()
        if case == 2:
            return Case2()
        raise NotImplementedError('Unknown case: %r'%case)

class Case1(Case):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Case1, self).__init__()
        print "Case1"

class Case2(Case):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Case2, self).__init__() 
        print "Case2"
```

You can extend as appropriate for args to pass to the initializer.  IN usage, you might see something like the following:

```
c1 = Case.factory(1)
c2 = Case.factory(2)
print type(c1), type(c2)
Case.factory(3)
```

Output would look like this:

```
Case1
Case2
<class '__main__.Case1'> <class '__main__.Case2'>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 19, in factory
NotImplementedError: Unknown case: 3
```